# how could i correct this error?

Tags: automated-tests, appium

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: unknown error: Device emulator-5554 is not online

Comment: Please post the server logs and the code -- how you are initialising driver.

Comment: also check `adb devices` lists out the emulator connected

Comment: make sure emulator is on and restart your appium server and try again.

Comment: Device emulator-5554 is not online, make sure that device is online,

Comment: Open command prompt and run command > adb device

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur for serveral reasons as per given below-

1. Invalid app package name in testcase.
2. check usb debugging for device in enabled.
3. If you are using device then check connected as media/MTP/file transfer.
4. check you can see the device by suing adb devices command.
5. check the server is started with right port number.
6. if device is connected then set emulator false in code.
7. uninstall previous versions of app from the device.

if you share complete log we can diagnose the problem effectively.

Regards,
Anuja